# Print running spec name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an issue while running my specs for a rails application with rake, it freezes on a certain spec. I would like to see what spec is running.

Comment: When the spec freezes, and you CTRL+C to break out of it, does it show you a stack trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have pretty funny answer for you.

The problem as I see it is that the name of the spec is written **after** the success or failure. And in your case it will never happen.

So you can bring a custom formatter! Yes, it will work. The problem is that base formatter defines a lot of points like when group starts, when example starts, but available formatters ( http://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/tree/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/ ) don't use the *example_started* method which is exactly the one you need.

Creating custom formatter is simple - just put this file into the spec/support/formatters/anxious_formatter.rb

```
class AnxiousFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter
  def example_started(example)
    message = "- #{example.description}"
    output.puts message
    output.flush
  end
end
```

Then you can run this with:

```
spec -r spec/support/formatters/anxious_formatter.rb -f AnxiousFormatter spec/models/...
```

The example above is for Rails 3 and RSpec 2.0 - for previous version it will slightly differ. More about custom formatters (for Rails 2 and RSpec 1.x) can be found on the project wiki: https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/custom-formatters

Funny, isn't it?